# Issue while uploading files on windows server with php

Tags: php, windows, file-upload

We are facing an issue in file uploading on windows server running php.  Bigger files are not uploading to the server.  The site is hosted in a windows 2008 server and the webserver is IIS 7.

Sometimes it is possible to upload 22MB files, but sometimes the upload fails for 10 MB file.  There is no error messages in the log files.

We have set very higher values in PHP.ini files.

```
max_execution_time 1800
max_input_time  1800
memory_limit       = 5000M
upload_max_filesize = 60M
max_file_uploads = 40
post_max_size  = 400
```

We also tried to increase the IIS upload limit by adding the values in web.conf file. It's also not solved the issue.

```
maxRequestLength="204800"
requestLengthDiskThreshold="204800"
executionTimeout="3600"
maxAllowedContentLength="204800000"
```

http://support.myeasyprojects.net/KB/a53/uploading-large-files-times-out.aspx

We are in the middle of a very confusing issue. Can anyone help us out on this?

Comment: if you have changed upload_max_filesize than verify it by using this function ini_get('upload_max_filesize'); sometimes changes in PHP.INI may not reflect on server until  we restart the server.

Comment: @ajay Thank you for the response.. We haven't changed this

Answer (score 1):

`post_max_size` should match `upload_max_filesize` because files are sent with POST.

Memory limit is very high, do you really need all that memory? 256M should be enough.

My suggested configuration:

```
memory_limit       = 256M
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size  = 64M
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.. This is one of the settings we tried after getting errors repeatedly.. But with this setting also files are not uploading properly. Worst is it works sometimes and it does not work always.

Comment: verify that your settings are valid, echoing them from your upload script

Comment: So your problem does not seem to be php related but instead IIS related.

Comment: Do you have any idea on what could be the ISS issue?

Comment: Try to see if it's a timeout issue. Maybe if your upload takes too much time, connection is reset by IIS. Do you run php as isapi module or cgi? IIS version?

Comment: IIS version is 7 and PHP is configured as FastCGI. PHP and IIS are installed by default with Plesk control panel.

Answer (score 0):

Need to do the following setting into the php.ini files. which is located into your c:\php
post_max_size (it should be greater than the upload_max_filesize);